# Errors from Facebook graph API on posting - Service temporarily unavailable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I get temporary errors from Facebook API after user is trying to share a post through "me/feed" route.

The error message is :

```
"message":"Service temporarily unavailable",
"type":"FacebookApiException",
"is_transient":true, "code":2,
"error_subcode":1609010,
"error_user_title":"URL Not Found",
"error_user_msg":"We had trouble using the URL you provided. Please try again later.",
"fbtrace_id":"DgSULoXJMfK"
```

Anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Also getting this; we haven't changed anything to evoke it.  Either Facebook has added a new "feature" to the API, or this is a (hopefully temporary) new bug...

Comment: The *only* other reference I can find to this new error message, dated Jan 15 - https://xfrocks.com/other/threads/bd-social-share-paid.82/page-22

Comment: Potentially relevant Facebook bugs:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1571642049794292/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1654284818174183/
I'm guessing (from your username) that you're Nimrod, so you probably already knew about the first one. :)

Comment: You're right. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: If I recall correctly, our system is successfully publishing now. (Maybe not; I have a lot of things on my plate :) ) is yours working better?

Comment: No, it still exists.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty confident this is a bug.  We're finding that the exact same post will fail when published to some pages, but succeed on others.  This sort of inconsistency along with the feedback of others (see below) suggests that this behavior is due to a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1571642049794292/

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error when try to use Facebook OAuth2 with `scope=email name`

Fixed by setting `scope=email`